# Import Jenkins pipeline and plugins to groovy library

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are developing a Shared Library for Jenkins pipelines.
As long as the library contained pure Groovy\Java we were able to write and execute tests.
Since I started adding some basic steps and plugin interaction, I am unable to determine which dependencies to add to pom and which components to import.

For example, in `GitHelper` I have

```groovy
  def getCommitHash() {
      git_commit = sh ( script: 'git rev-parse HEAD', returnStdout: true ).trim()
      return git_commit
  }
```

Which causes the following exception:

```groovy
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: org.***.GitHelper.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[script:git rev-parse HEAD, returnStdout:true]]
```

Same happening when I try to call for `currentBuild.build().environment.BUILD_NUMBER`

Another example is in ArtifactoryHelper creator:

```groovy
ArtifactoryHelper(String artifactory_url, String credentilasId){
    artifactoryServer = Artifactory.newServer url: artifactory_url, credentialsId: credentilasId
}
```

Which causes the similar exception:

```groovy
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Artifactory for class: org.***.ArtifactoryHelper
```

I tried following imports without success:

```groovy
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.*
import org.jfrog.hudson.*
```

So the question is which dependencies and imports are required in order to develop, test and debug Groovy library that interacts with Jenkins pipeline steps and plugins?

Comment: I'd recommend using a Gradle plugin I developed [here](https://github.com/mkobit/jenkins-pipeline-shared-libraries-gradle-plugin) for testing. One of the libraries it uses is [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit). [JENKINS-33925](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33925) is an open issue for addressing this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to mock and create tests for Artifactory.newServer?